# How to get English word alone from 100 words using Java program

Tags: java

I have 100 words. All 100 words are look like this.

```
EnglishWord,EngMeaning,NumberofW… meaning,31
```

In that I want to retrieve `EnglishWord`, e.g. `Friendship` alone for 100 words by using Java program.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem entirely - it would help to give a better example of the problem space, as the "100 words" are not in a format I recognize from the snippet.  Also, if this is homework it would be constructive, both to your learning and our ability to help, if you attempt to solve it and ask specific questions about areas where you are stumped.

Comment: How are those words stored? List, array, just String?

Comment: It looks like you're dealing with a bunch of values, all separated by commas?  I would research String.split or StringTokenizer, first.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a "body" (main string), containing a list of substrings and you want to retrieve any specific one substring from within.

This looks a lot like homework/exercise, so I'll avoid giving you a ready-to-roll answer, since you need to achieve a solution yourself for it to be of any value, but the general steps you will need are the following:

---

**1:**

Be able to separate each substring (entry) from the others (the base string) in an organized fashion.
This can be done (for the string case), as @kylc said, with String's split function, which uses a REGEX (PATTERN) to define divisors (one or more), that then is/are used to divide the string into an array of multiple substrings.

`String[] arrayOfEntries /*something to hold the result*/ = yourStringVar.split("," /*your split regex pattern*/);`

NOTE: For more information on these, here are the links: [String's split function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

---

**2:**

Be able to acquire any specific entry withing an array of entries.
This is best done with a function you can reuse for other works. You need to define a "target" (what/which is going to be acquired) and a "source" (group of entries to acquire "target" from).

All you have to do is loop the "source", and for each entry there, compare to "target" for a match; When a match is found, just `return` it.

---

That's it! The rest is up to you!